# Comparing two algorithms, one is parameter free while the other is not

Tags: cross-validation, pca, model-selection

I wish to compare two algorithm for subspace approximation (similar to PCA). One algorithm is parameter free, while the other is not. I use cross validation to set value to this parameter, and then run both algorithms on the test data.

What is the right way to compare the two algorithms? It seems that the second algorithm may have some advantage, since I used data to determine its parameter.